# Не могу получить значение int из txt файла

Tags: python

```
last_post = open('last.txt','r+')
for line in last_post:
    last = int(line)
    break
if last == 20:
    hour = 6
    last_post.write(str(hour))
```

```
last_post = open('last.txt','r+')
last = int(last_post.readline())
```

```
last = int(last_post.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

выдает

```
if last == 20:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'last' referenced before assignment
```

[image: в файле есть число]

Comment: А вы файл сохранили? А то может он у вас был пустой, открыли в блокноте, дописали данные, но ещё не сохранили? По-другому такая ошибка вряд ли объяснима.

Comment: Файл сохранён в директории с '.py' файлом.

Comment: Приведите имеющий отношение к вопросу код целиком, не по кускам. Сейчас непонятно - вы один раз читаете из файла или два раза. И в каком порядке у вас что идёт, где у вас проверка `if` по коду относительно чтения файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрал цикл, который читал файл без его открытия и закрытия и выдавал пустое значение строки.